# bigvideo.js - stack DIVs over and under bigvideo container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video.js

So I've started playing around with [**bigvideo.js**](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) (which is built on top of video.js) and it works fine for the basic usage of having a fixed background video over the whole screen. I have also managed to show it inside of a div.

My problem though, is that I can't seem to stack other DIVs with other content over or under the bigvideo.js container div, and I can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

My HTML:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 300px;">
<h1>hi there</h1>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 500px;" id="intro-video-container">
</div>
```

JS firing up bigvideo:

```
$(function() {

    var BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('#intro-video-container'),useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    BV.show('intro.mp4',{ambient:true});
});
```

So the video container div ALWAYS gets stuck up to the left top of the body, no matter if I try to force it down with margin-top, or place divs before it, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use container div (so called wrapping) in your page where you will place the desired content (as on the plugin's [example](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient.html) page):

**CSS**

```
.box { 
    background:#444; background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.main {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 50px 440px 220px;
    min-width:300px;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;-moz-transition-duration:0.6s;-ms-transition-duration:0.6s;-o-transition-duration:0.6s;transition-duration:0.6s;
}

.dimmed {
   color: #ccc;
}

#big-video-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="big-video-wrap"></div>

 <div class="main">
     <div id="overview" class="box">
        <h1>BigVideo<span class="dimmed"><small>.</small>js</span></h1>
        <h2>Simple Ambient Video Example</h2>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    var BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('#big-video-wrap'),useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    BV.show('intro.mp4',{ambient:true});
});
```

**EDIT:**

Now, it is more clear what you are trying to achieve, the simplest solution is to include an `iframe` on place of the `div`, which points to your full-screen video page.
I.e. create page `video.html` with all initializations and plug-in includes, then use it as source of your `iframe` on main page. Your `iframe` can be styled to match the desired dimensions (for example 100% width and 300px height).

Comment: thanks for your answer. That I can achieve. My problem is that I want stuff on the page above and under the video div. Placing content on top of the video background is no problemo. Though if I place the video in a div it ALWAYS get stuck to the top left of the body. I just want a little div with a background video, just as if I wanted a div with a background image.

Comment: Yes, now it is clear what you want, see the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update, here is an illustration of what I kind of what to achieve:

[image]

Comment: In that case it doesn't sound like bigvideo.js is the right tool for this job. Use a regular (video.js) player, with css to ensure it's the page with. btw, it fits the Stack Overflow Q&A format better to edit the question than post an update as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, I've started looking at that way to do it. A bit of fiddling to make it responsive and still don't get any black borders and stuff, but I'm sure it'll work out somehow! And OK, thx for the Q&A advice.